# How do you limit an array subelement in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have the following data model in Mongo:

```
{
   _id: ...,
   name: "...",
   obj: {...},
   list: [ ... ],
}
```

Now let's say, my `list` array is very long, and I don't want to grab the whole document every time. So I want to get `obj` and `name`, but only grab the last 5 elements in `list`. How do you do this with with Mongo? I'm using pymongo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `$slice` operator. Docs are [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements).

The syntax you are looking for is something like this:

```
db.coll.find({}, {obj:1, name: 1, list:{$slice: -5}}); // last 5
```

Note that this will also return the `_id` field by default. If you do not want the `_id` add `_id:0` in front of `obj:1`. This is the JS syntax, but the python syntax will be very close.

Comment: [docs.mongodb/$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Answer (score 0):

use **$slice** operator to limit array elements

```
GeoLocation.find({},{name: 1, geolocation:{$slice: -5}})
    .then((result) => {
      res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: `Something went wrong. ${err}` });
});
```

where geolocation is array of data, from that we get last 5 record.